# Mongoose: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, mongoose, promise, angular-promise

I have this simple function i my controller:

```
newUserRequest: async (req, res) => {
    const newRequest = new Request(req.body)
    const thesi = await Thesi.findById(req.params.thesiId)
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId)

    newRequest.user = user
    newRequest.thesi = thesi
    await newRequest.save()

    user.requests.push(newRequest)
    thesi.requests.push(newRequest)

    await user.save()
    await thesi.save()

    res.status(201).json(user)
}
```

And i call this through my service in my component like this:

```
this._usersService.addRequest(this.user, this.addRequestData, thesi).subscribe(
   res => { ... })
```

and my service function is this one:

```
addRequest(user, request, thesi){
   const id = typeof user === 'string' ? user : user._id;
   const id2 = typeof thesi === 'string' ? thesi : thesi._id;
   const url = `${this._users}/${id}/${id2}/requests`;
   return this.http.post<any>(url, request)
}
```

The thing is:

When i call addRequest, in mlab the request is going as expected, BUT in network the request is pending for like 2 minutes and then it sends the message to mlab again and makes a double addRequest..

So in simple words, i call the addRequest function, it works ok, but it will go inside the subscribe block after 2 minutes and will send automatically another request to the server.

This is the full warning mongoose msg:

> (node:12555) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum
>   call stack size exceeded
>       at RegExp.test ()
>
> ...............
>
> (node:12555) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise whichwas not
>   handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)

Comment: Can you share your `Request`, `Thesi` and `User` models? Is `newRequest.user` just the id, the entire `user` object? Maybe there is a loop somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. so the problem was here:

```
newRequest.user = user
newRequest.thesi = thesi
```

I don't know the reason, but when i delete these two lines it works ok.

If someone knows why feel free to share :)